# What texts should be studied after services on erev Yom Kippur?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, yom-kippur

I understand that there is a tradition to do some learning following Shul on erev Yom Kippur.  What texts are recommended for studying during this time?

Answer (score 8):

Try Mishnayos Yoma. These mishnayos discuss the Temple Service for the day of Yom Kippur, and are traditionally printed in Yom Kippur machzorim (prayer books) after Maariv prayers of the night of Yom Kippur.

I would also recommend spending some time looking at the prayers for the next day -- they are long and unfamiliar, and reading them with an English translation and commentary *before* trying to say them can be very helpful in focusing on the prayers of the day.

Comment: So does mine :)