# Why does Chabad do hakafot erev Shemini Atzeret

Tags: simchat-torah, shmini-atzeres

Growing up, I typically went to a Chabad and I have noticed that they have hakafot on erev Shemini Atzeret (meaning the night of Shemini Atzeret). What is the reason and why do they do this?

Comment: They do it on _Sh"A_ not on _erev Sh"A_ (which is _Hosha'na Raba_). (Unless you're referring to circling the _bima_ during _hosha'nos_? I don't often see/hear that called "hakafot".) And they're not alone: many other groups do, too.

Comment: @msh210, they do it by Maariv, so in the vocabulary I'm familiar with, that's still considered **erev** hayom.

Comment: Oh. I'm wholly unfamiliar with that use of the word. I wonder, though, whether that's what [this person](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45872) meant.

Comment: Are you referring to Hakafot Shniyot?

Comment: Is there a reason to do so on the second day of Shemini Atzeret that isn't equally applicable to the first?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, Simchat Torah isn't just just acharon shel yom tov, it was established as its own chag in Bavel, see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10784/4504

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt What does that mean "it's own chag"?? Simchat Torah is just Acharon Shel Yom Tov.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it doesn't have typical acharon shel y"t observances though.

Comment: @noach yes it surely does. no melakha. Hallel. Musaf. Leining. Haftara. Kiddush. What's missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Baal HaTanya writes in his siddur:

> מנהג ותיקין הוא לעשות יום שמיני עצרת גם כן כמו בשמחת תורה
>
> It is a custom of the ancients(?) to do on Shmini Atzeres like on Simchas on Torah ...

And then going on to describe Hakafos.

Rabbi Nachum Greenwald [notes](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=886&cat=9&haoro=12) that the language seems to paraphrase the Mishnas Chassidim, but the Mishnas Chassidim is talking about Shimini Atzeres in Eretz Yisroel.

He then goes on to note that the custom of doing it on both nights is common among all Chassidim (not specifically Chabad) as this was the custom of the Mizritcher Maggid. In terms of source, he also points to the [Tur Borekes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44445&st=&pgnum=820&hilite=) (by a student of Rabbi Chaim Vital) who argues specifically for Hakafos at night having a special connection to Shimini Atzeres specifically (more so than Simchas Torah night) kabbalistically, but feels inadequate to actually introduce the practice.

Comment: yishai, I think the second word of that quote should be translated 'of ancient ones', i.e., it's an old custom... (rather than 'and a rectification' - reading 'vatikkin' not 've-tikkun').

Comment: @paquda, you are correct. Thanks. For some reason I always read it with a vov instead of the second yud. Now is it ancient or zelous?

Comment: good point, I don't know

Comment: I just saw a note in the 'Shai LaMora' edition of the siddur ba'al ha-tanya that indicates you were mekhavein to the wording of an early edition:

בסדור אדמוה"ז שנדפס בברדיטשוב בשנת תקע"ח הנוסחא "ותיקון". ויתכן שהוא לשון תקנה. וראה ספר השיחות ה'תש"ו-השי"ת עמוד 378, ובהתועדויות תשמ"ה חלק ה' עמ' 445.

Comment: @ezra, although your translation is not unreasonable, I'll stick with my last edit on this.

Comment: @yishai what's mishnas chassidim?

Comment: @false https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Hai_Ricchi

Answer (score 0):

There is a minhag to do it then to feel more connected with the Jews in eretz yisrael.

Source : siddurim and Chabad shul.

Comment: which siddurim?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin chabad siddurim-tehilas hashem.